# AutoMapAttribute with ReverseMap & TypeConverter to create 2-way maps?

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

I have a device I'm communicating with. It returns a number of bitflags in various integer representations (`byte`, `ushort`, `uint`).

Currently, to show them on the UI, they are mapped into ViewModels:

```cs
 // The ViewModel, annotated
[AutoMap(typeof(byte), TypeConverter = typeof(FlagConverter))]
public record FlagVM(bool One, bool Two)
{ 
  // And its converter
  public class FlagConverter : ITypeConverter<byte, FlagVM> {
    public FlagVM Convert(byte src, FlagVM dst, ResolutionContext c)
        => new((src & 1) > 0, (src & 2) > 0);
}
```

`AutoMapAttribute` is used because there are 50+ other structures, and `AutoMapper` can easily be configured for the whole Assembly:

```cs
var mapper = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
  cfg.AddMaps(this.GetType().Assembly)
).CreateMapper();

mapper.Map<FlagVM>((byte)2)
  .Should().Be(new FlagVM(false, true)); //easy!
```

---

Now, onto the problem: I also need to create **reverse maps**, back into the numeric representations. Easy enough to add to the converters:

```
public class FlagConverter
    : ITypeConverter<byte, FlagVM>, ITypeConverter<FlagVM, byte> {

  public FlagVM Convert(byte src, FlagVM dst, ResolutionContext c)
      => new(One:(src & 1) > 0, Two:(src & 2) > 0);

  public byte Convert(FlagVM src, byte dst, ResolutionContext c)
      => (byte)((src.One ? 1 : 0) | (src.Two ? 2 : 0));
}
```

That's all well and good, except now I cannot use `AutoMapAttribute` anymore, because simply adding `ReverseMap` does not work:

```cs
// The TypeConverter is not applied to the reverse map
[AutoMap(typeof(byte), TypeConverter = typeof(FlagConverter), ReverseMap = true)]
```

The only way I could get two-way mapping is by configuring *every single one* of them (either manually or reflected)

```cs
var mapper = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
  cfg.CreateMap<byte, FlagDto>().ConvertUsing<FlagConverter>();
  cfg.CreateMap<FlagDto, byte>().ConvertUsing<FlagConverter>(); //reverse
  // .. repeat 50+ times
  // .. or use reflection to find all ITypeConverter<> implementations.
).CreateMapper();

// Forward map
mapper.Map<FlagVM>((byte)2).Should().Be(new FlagVM(false, true));
// Reverse map
mapper.Map<byte>(new FlagVM(false, true)).Should().Be(2);
```

Yes, at the end of the day, AutoMapper will do reflection to find the attributes anyway; But the whole program is configured using attribute-based mapping, and I much prefer for these structures to be *consistent* with rest of the codebase.

Is there really no way to combine `AutoMapAttribute`, `ReverseMap`, and `TypeConverter` to create 2-way maps?

*Note: .NET6, AutoMapper 11.0*

Comment: There is no need for `ReverseMap` here, you can simply create two maps.

Comment: I have edited the question to make it clearer that this is for attribute-based configuration.  And to pre-empt the suggestion to "just annotate the other class", I will emphasise that this is being applied against built-in types I have no control over (`byte`, `uint` etc)

Comment: Then you should use the fluent API, the attributes API is only useful in the simplest cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in the comments, this is not something one can do with the attributes API.

We ended up automating the fluent registrations by simply scanning the whole Assembly for all implementations of `ITypeConverter<,>` and registering them one by one.

```cs
private static void CreateTypeConverterMaps(IMapperConfigurationExpression mapperCfg) {
  var converters = typeof(AType).Assembly
    .GetTypes()
    .SelectMany(typ => typ
      .GetInterfaces()
      .Where(itf => itf.IsGenericType)
      .Where(itf => itf.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ITypeConverter<,>))
      .Select(itf => new { Interface = itf, Class = typ }));
  foreach (var conv in converters) {
    // We know there's two TypeArgs, as we filter by <,> above
    var srcType = conv.Interface.GenericTypeArguments[0];
    var dstType = conv.Interface.GenericTypeArguments[1];
    mapperCfg // Register the map+converter
      .CreateMap(srcType, dstType)
      .ConvertUsing(conv.Class);
  }
}
```